# How to determine the Direction of Tension Force while working with Pulleys?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

I had been studying about the Mechanical Advantage and Velocity Ratio of Pulleys. In the diagrams and derivation, they had considered the load and effort to be equal to the tension force in the string and concluded that MA=1 since MA=L/D and L=D=Tension Force.

From what I understood of Tension, it was just some force being transmitted through a string in the same direction as the applied force. However, in the diagrams in my textbook, the Force of Tension has been always opposite the force of Load and Effort.

Also, while studying Block and Tackle system, all the info that was given was 'Tension is being applied at 5 segments, therefore L=5T'(I have attached the diagram). Please let me know if my understanding of Tension Force is wrong.

My three Questions are:

1. How do I determine the direction of Tension force
2. If I am pulling down on a String going over a pulley, why is the direction of the tension force opposite my applied force
3. Why is L=5T? Specifically, where does the 5 come from?

[image: Block and Tackle system of 5 pulleys.]

[Here's the diagram of a system of pulleys given in my book.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Mcf.png)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of tension, I believe that it is a force that keeps a taut string the way it is physically perceived by us. It is just like normal force between 2 surface or stress and strain in an iron rod. You just fully taut a string and keep it on the ground and leave it be without applying any more forces and it will have zero tension, again just like how normal force does not come into play unless you press the objects against each other.

Now, for the direction of tension, I think confusion is coming as you are trying to look at free body diagrams of different systems together. Assuming that the problems you are dealing with are with ideal strings (strings that do not break and are massless), the tension on each segment of the string is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction at each point on the string. This is so because for the FBD of each differential segment of string, the net force on it has to be zero, even if the string has got some acceleration. This comes from the equation $F=ma$ where mass of the ideal string is zero. So the direction of tension will depend on which part of the differential string you are taking inside your system when making the FBD.

As for $L=5T$, here the system is taken to be the load and the two lower pullies. So the total upward force on the system is equal to $5T$ ($2T$ on the lower pulley, $2T$ on the upper pulley and $1T$ on the hook) and the downward force is weight of the load. So, for maintaining equilibrium, $total\ upward\ force=total\ lower\ force => 5T=L$

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Tension itself does not have a direction. It is not a vector, but part of a tensor.  A taut  string exerts a force on whatever it is attached to, and that force has the same magnitude as $T$ and is in the direction of the string away from the object. The forces exerted on objects at opposite ends of a taut  massless string are  equal and opoosite.  The arrows in your diagrams indicate the forces exerted on whatever objects are of interest for that problem.